# gunicorn not Binding showing some package error?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, nginx

**I have installed PostgreSQL and Nginx and all those things's working fine please let me help for this error**

it' showing error after tying to bind my project but I tested another sample project but it's working fine

I can't able to bind gunicorn please help me **502 Bad Gateway**

```
[2020-12-11 15:30:39 +0000] [30480] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-12-11 15:30:39 +0000] [30480] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (30480)
[2020-12-11 15:30:39 +0000] [30480] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-12-11 15:30:39 +0000] [30482] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 30482
[2020-12-11 15:30:39 +0000] [30482] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ubuntu/Movie-Booking/bookshow/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 83, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 70, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 177, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 122, in import_module
    raise TypeError(msg.format(name))
TypeError: the 'package' argument is required to perform a relative import for '.settings'
[2020-12-11 15:30:39 +0000] [30482] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 30482)
[2020-12-11 15:30:39 +0000] [30480] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2020-12-11 15:30:39 +0000] [30480] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

```
(env) ubuntu@ip-172-31-36-203:~/Movie-Booking$ sudo supervisorctl status
gunia:gunione                    BACKOFF   Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Postgres. It is a Django issue `TypeError: the 'package' argument is required to perform a relative import for '.settings'` You will need to provide more information; Django version?, How AWS is involved? The Gunicorn/Nginx setup?

Answer (score 0):

Problem with dir paths might you are using some relative path that's what's causing problem may be while running gunicorn you are no in right dir

Comment: I have fixed that problem it was in the wsgi.py file inside that file the application name .settings was not showing there. but don't know how it's gone from there but I have added that content inside the file and it's working fine